# JAVA Increment Counter When A Specific Color Appears When Clicking JButton

Tags: java, arrays, swing, counter, jbutton

I am making a program where the user clicks on a JButton which has the default background color BLUE. Every time the user clicks the JButton, the background randomly cycles through array of colors. Each time background is RED, a JLabel prints out an incrementing counter.
I can get the JButton to cycle randomly through the array of colors. When the first RED shows up, the counter increments 1. But every time after when a RED comes up, the counter does not increment. I cannot get the counter to continue incrementing after the initial count.
Here is the code for the button:

```
        //label for counter
        JLabel lblRedCounter = new JLabel("Red Counter: 00");
        lblRedCounter.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(31, 3, 31, 3));
        lblRedCounter.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        lblRedCounter.setOpaque(true);
        lblRedCounter.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        panel.add(lblRedCounter);

        //button to change background and initiate counter
        JButton btnClickMe = new JButton("Click Me");
        btnClickMe.setFocusable(false);
        btnClickMe.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(33, 47, 33, 47));
        btnClickMe.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        btnClickMe.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        btnClickMe.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnClickMe.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {               
                //create arraylist of colors
                colors = new ArrayList<>();
                colors.add(Color.BLUE);
                colors.add(Color.RED);
                colors.add(Color.GREEN);
                colors.add(Color.ORANGE);
                colors.add(Color.MAGENTA);

                //creates random object
                Random rand = new Random();
                //random object cycles through 5 places to match array length
                int num = rand.nextInt(5);

                //cycles randomly through array of colors
                btnClickMe.setBackground(colors.get(num));

                //default for counter to be used when RED is background
                int counter = 0;
                /**
                 * This only seems to cycle once
                 * Checks if background is RED, increments counter
                 * Changes output of JLabel lblRedCounter
                 */
                if (btnClickMe.getBackground() == Color.RED)
                {
                    counter++;
                    lblRedCounter.setText("Red Counter: " + counter);
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(btnClickMe);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your int variable outside the actionPerfomed method and make it an instance variable (or static though that is usually not recommended) instead. Right now you are initializing a new variable with 0 each time actionPerformed is called.